# Boot Configuration DIP Switch on Snapdragon 810

Tags: linux, arm, embedded, boot, arm64

I've just purchased a Snapdragon 810 development board to evaluate some ARMv8 assembly codes on Cortex-A57 and Cortex-A53. My problem is that the default OS is `Android 5.0` and I want to have an access to Linux console for debugging through my codes and messing up with CPU frequency and other stuff. I tried inserting Linux mounted SD card and reboot the board, but I couldn't figure out how to change the primary boot option on this board. I know I should change the boot DIP switch and set the SD card boot "ON", but it has 8 switches and I cannot find the configuration manual on the web. Does anyone know what is the code for SD card boot on this board?

Comment: You should take a look to schematics and see at which pin each dip switch is connected. Then look at the GPU datasheet to see how to set them. What is the demo board name?

Comment: I searched almost everywhere to find the pin combination but there is not reference available on the web for this board. I have already emailed the customer support but they haven't replied yet. The board is "DragonBoard Development Kit Based on Qualcomm Snapdragon 810 Processor (APQ8094)" by Intrinsyc @LPs

Comment: If there are no info, wait for support reply. BTW is the actual bootloader u-boot or somethnig that can manage USB, NFS and so on? If yes you could stop it and change its environment set to start from USB, NFS..

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I have written to Intrynsic to ask them about this and they answered to me:

*There is only eMMC boot support. No USB or Sdcard support in the software.*